# How to calculate the second functional derivative of the action of a one-particle system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Given the Lagrangian $$L(q,\dot{q})=m\dot{q}^2/2-V(q)$$ and the corresponding action $$S[q]\equiv\int_0^t dt' (m\dot{q}^2/2-V(q)),$$ I need to be able to evaluate  the second functional derivative $\frac{\delta^2S[q]}{\delta q(t) \delta q(t')}|_{q=q_{cl}}$.
According to Altland/Simon's CMFT, 
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^t dt \int dt' r(t) \frac{\delta^2 S[q]}{\delta q(t) \delta q(t')}|_{q=q_{cl}} r(t') = -\frac{1}{2} \int dt r(t) [m\partial_t^2 + V''(q_{cl}(t))]r(t).
\end{equation*}
My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the $\partial_t^2$ part when evaluating the function derivative. I would suspect that it's coming from taking the functional derivative of the kinetic energy part of the action. However, when using the definition 
$$\frac{\delta F[f]}{\delta f(x)} \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}(F[f+\epsilon \delta_x]-F[f]),$$ I'm left with some really odd first- and second-derivatives of the Dirac delta function instead.

Could someone please show me how to evaluate these functional derivatives?

Comment: Integration by parts will solve all your troubles.

Comment: More on higher functional derivatives: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123481/2451

Comment: Shouldn't $dtr(t)$ in the long equation be $dtdr(t)$? Where is the $\partial_t^2$ part?

Comment: @MarkMitchison According to the answer below this isn't enough.

Comment: Oh, I already see the part I mentioned. $r$ is called $q$. That's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I know how to do this by simply expanding the action as a Taylor series in the deviation $r(t)$.

Expand the action
\begin{align}
\delta S =& S[q_{\mathrm{cl}} + r(t)] - S[q_{\mathrm{cl}}(t)] \\
   =& \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t' \cdot\left\{ \frac{m}{2}\left[\partial_{t'}( q_{\mathrm{cl}} + r)\right]^2 - V(q_{\mathrm{cl}} + r) 
    -\frac{m}{2}\left[\partial_{t'} q_{\mathrm{cl}} \right]^2 + V(q_{\mathrm{cl}}) \right\} \\
   = & \int_0^t\mathrm{d}t' \cdot\left\{O(r) + \frac{m}{2} (\partial_{t'}r)^2 - \frac{1}{2}V''(q_{\mathrm{cl}})r^2
    + O(r^{3}) + \cdots\right\}
\end{align}
where $O(r^n)$ means the $n$th order term. Then use integration by parts
\begin{align}
  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\cdot \left[\partial_{t'}r(t')\right] \left[\partial_{t'}r(t')\right]
  =& \left.r(t')\partial_{t'}r(t')\right|_0^t - \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\cdot r(t')\partial_{t'}^{2}r(t') \\
  = & - \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\cdot r(t')\partial_{t'}^{2}r(t')
\end{align}
where we have used the fact that $r(0)=r(t)=0$ . So we get the second order term of $S$
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \mathrm{d}t \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\cdot r(t) \frac{\delta^2 S[q]}{\delta q(t) \delta q(t')}|_{q=q_{cl}} r(t') = -\frac{1}{2} \int \mathrm{d}t \cdot r(t) [m\partial_t^2 + V''(q_{cl}(t))]r(t).
\end{align}

Reference:

[Appendix A of *Density Functional Theory An Advanced Course* by Eberhard Engel, Reiner M. Dreizler](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-642-14090-7%2F1.pdf) may be helpful to understand the relation between the Taylor expansion and functional derivative.

Comment: Hi there! Nice answer. Did you write it from memory?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I am reading Altland/Simon's CMFT now and also meet this problem.  After read Appendix A of *Density Functional Theory An Advanced Course*, I did this derivative.