# Mixed second functional derivative not symmetrical with respect to order of differentiation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives, density-functional-theory

I have a functional $E$, which is a functional of two different functions and their gradients:
$$ E[\psi_1,\psi_2] = \int d^3\mathbf{x} ~ \varepsilon\{\mathbf{x}\}$$
where I'm using $\varepsilon\{\mathbf{x}\}$ as short-hand for
$$ \varepsilon\{\mathbf{x}\} = \varepsilon\left(\mathbf{x};\psi_1(\mathbf{x}),\nabla\psi_1(\mathbf{x}),\psi_2(\mathbf{x}),\nabla\psi_2(\mathbf{x})\right) .$$
(This is coming from a density functional theory problem where the $\psi$ are orbitals, so there are actually many of them, but just two illustrates the problem.)

I would like to calculate the mixed second functional derivative of $E$
$$ \frac{\delta^2 E}{\delta \psi_1 (\mathbf{r}) \delta \psi_2 (\mathbf{r}')}. $$
As I understand it, the two functional derivatives here should commute, so the order of taking these derivatives shouldn't matter - however, by following what seems like reasonably simple steps, I find that this is not the case (see below for my work so far). I cannot find anything on mixed functional derivatives like this after a lot of searching, but potentially I have missed something. **Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?**

*Derivation:*

First, I take the functional derivative of $E$ wrt $\psi_1(\mathbf{r})$. The result of this kind of operation is fairly easy to find (e.g. http://mbpt-domiprod.wikidot.com/calculation-of-gga-kernel), and we get:
$$ \frac{\delta E}{\delta \psi_1(\mathbf{r})} = \frac{\partial \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}\}}{\partial \psi_1 (\mathbf{r})} - \nabla.\frac{\partial\varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}\}}{\partial\nabla\psi_1(\mathbf{r})} = f(\mathbf{r}). $$
Now, we need to take the functional derivative of $f(\mathbf{r})$ wrt $\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')$. We  write $f(\mathbf{r})$ as a functional:
$$ f(\mathbf{r}) \rightarrow F_\mathbf{r}[f] = \int d^3\mathbf{x} ~ f(\mathbf{x}) \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}). $$
Using the same result as before, with $\varepsilon\{\mathbf{x}\}$ replaced by $f(\mathbf{x})\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x})$, we can write the second derivative as
\begin{align} \frac{\delta^2 E}{\delta \psi_1 (\mathbf{r}) \delta \psi_2 (\mathbf{r}')} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_2 (\mathbf{r}')} \left[f(\mathbf{r}')\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\right] - \nabla'.\frac{\partial}{\partial\nabla'\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')} \left[f(\mathbf{r}')\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\right] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_2 (\mathbf{r}')} \left[\frac{\partial \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r'}\}}{\partial \psi_1 (\mathbf{r'})}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') - \nabla'.\frac{\partial\varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}'\}}{\partial\nabla'\psi_1(\mathbf{r}')}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\right] \\
& ~ ~ ~ ~ - \nabla'.\frac{\partial}{\partial\nabla'\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')} \left[\frac{\partial \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r'}\}}{\partial \psi_1 (\mathbf{r'})}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') - \nabla'.\frac{\partial\varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}'\}}{\partial\nabla'\psi_1(\mathbf{r}')}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\right] \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r'}\}}{\partial \psi_1 (\mathbf{r'}) \partial \psi_2 (\mathbf{r'})}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') - \nabla'.\frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}'\}}{\partial\nabla'\psi_1(\mathbf{r}')\partial\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') \\
& ~ ~ ~ ~ - \nabla'.\left[ \frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r'}\}}{\partial \psi_1 (\mathbf{r'})\partial \nabla'\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') \right] + \nabla_2'.\left[ \nabla_1'.\frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon\{\mathbf{r}'\}}{\partial\nabla_1'\psi_1(\mathbf{r}')\partial\nabla_2'\psi_2(\mathbf{r}')}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\right].
\end{align}
I've used subscripts to make it clear which $\nabla$ is dotted with which in the 4th term. For the final step, I've allowed $\nabla$ and the derivative wrt $\psi_2$ or $\nabla\psi_2$ to commute in the 2nd and 4th terms, which I believe is valid, but this is the step I'm least sure on. However, I don't think this affects the main issue here, which is to do with the $\delta$-functions.

This expression is clearly not symmetrical in the order of derivation, because of the $\delta$-function inside the derivatives - if I did the whole thing again but differentiating wrt $\psi_2$ first, the $\delta$-function would move inside the square brackets in the 2nd term, and move outside them in the 3rd term, whilst $\nabla_1$ and $\nabla_2$ would be flipped in the 4th term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that OP incorrectly applies the Euler-Lagrange formula for the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of a local functional to a non-local functional. Instead it is better to use
$$ \frac{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}{\delta \phi^{\beta}(y)}~=~\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}~\delta^n(x-y)$$
and appropriate generalizations of elementary rules in calculus, such as, e.g., the Leibniz rule,
cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/123501/2451).
Then it is straightforward to check that the 2nd functional derivative is symmetric for a sufficiently smooth functional.

*Example:*

If $$S[\phi,\psi]~=~\int\!d^nx~{\cal L}(\phi(x),\psi(x),\partial\phi(x),\partial\psi(x),x)$$ is a local functional of first order, then the 1st functional derivative is the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}~=~\frac{\partial{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\phi(x)}-\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{\partial{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\phi_{,\mu}(x)}, $$
and then the 2nd functional derivative becomes symmetric:
$$\begin{align}&\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta\psi(y)\delta\phi(x)}\cr
~=~&\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi(x)\partial\phi(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)+\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi_{,\nu}(x)\partial\phi(x)}\frac{d}{dx^{\nu}}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\cr
~-~&\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\left[\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi(x)\partial\phi_{,\mu}(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)+\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi_{,\nu}(x)\partial\phi_{,\mu}(x)}\frac{d}{dx^{\nu}}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\right]\cr
~=~&\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi(x)\partial\phi(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\cr
~-~&\frac{d}{dy^{\nu}}\left[\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi_{,\nu}(x)\partial\phi(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\right]-\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\left[\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi(x)\partial\phi_{,\mu}(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\right]\cr
~+~&\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{d}{dy^{\nu}}\left[\frac{\partial^2{\cal L}(x)}{\partial\psi_{,\nu}(x)\partial\phi_{,\mu}(x)}\delta^n(x\!-\!y)\right]\cr
~=~& (\phi(x)\leftrightarrow\psi(y)). \end{align}$$
In the last equality we used the identity
$$ f(x)\delta^n(x\!-\!y)~=~f(y)\delta^n(x\!-\!y)$$
for the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), and that partial derivative commutes for a sufficiently smooth Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I had a few questions for clarification: 1. so the issue is in the step where I say 'Using the same result as before...', when this isn't valid? 2. Is f(r) non-local due to the presence of the delta-function? 3. Are you able to expand slightly more on what you mean exactly by the Leibniz rule, as I haven't come across the term before? How to proceed is not completely clear to me.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link to your previous answer. I think I understand how this fixes the issue - when we take the functional derivative of f(r) wrt psi_2(r'), the functional derivative commutes with all the partial derivatives contained within f(r), meaning we have those various partial derivatives acting on (delta epsilon{r})/(delta psi_2 (r)). Going back to the definition of the functional derivative, you find this is not simply f(r') delta(r-r'), but a similar function where the divergence operator acts on delta(r-r') as well. This fixes the asymmetry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will mark this as an accepted answer.